# RavenDB: how to check permissions for a user, wanting to perform an operation on a specific document

Tags: authorization, bundle, ravendb

I have a multi-part, possibly confusing question... it's been a while 
since I've dug in to the Authorization bundle, so it's taking me a bit 
to remember how it all works. Bear with me as I struggle to make sense 
of my thoughts, here :)

The majority of the code that I'm writing in my system uses a call to 
the documentSession.IsAllowed method to check and see if the 
AuthorizationUser has permissions for the Activity specified. This has 
been working wonderfully for us, no problem. I'm expanding my app's 
authorization to make use of tags now and I'm wondering:

Does the documentSession.IsAllowed method account for Tags on document 
permissions, role permissions, and user permissions?

For example:

If I have Bob assigned to the Manager role. The Manager role is 
assigned a permission to allow a "Review" operation, with a Tag of 
"ReadyForReview" on that permission.  How do I make a call to 
documentSession.isAllowed in a way that verifies that Bob can "Review" 
things that are tagged "ReadyForReview" ?

I realize that I may be asking the wrong question and/or looking at 
this from the wrong perspective. If I am going about this wrong, 
please let me know.

The end goal is really to say "Can Bob review this assignment?" Where 
an Assignment is a document in RavenDB that may or may not have a 
"ReadyForReview" tag. Bob should only be allowed to review assignments 
that have the "ReadyForReview" tag. I would like to have a method that 
gives me a boolean value telling me if Bob can review that document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Derick,

In addition to simply `IsAllowed`, you also have `IsOperationAllowedOnDocument`.
That allows you to ask security questions about a specific document instance, not just globally.

Comment: Where does the 'IsOperationAllowedOnDocument' method exist?

Comment: i found it... it's in the "advanced" namespace. Small suggestion: move this somewhere easier to find. I could have saves several hours of headache if I had known this method existed.